# How do I monitor how much time I'm spending on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a table on MS SQL 2005 or 2008 servers that will show my boss how much work I'm doing?

Maybe something that would show how often my database tables/views/etc are being executed/queried against?

Comment: I pity you if your boss wants to the minute increments of how much time you're spending with sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably look at setting up a trace.  You can read up on [Data Access Tracing here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421.aspx).

Once you are done doing that, write a script that makes it look like you are working 24 hours a day and ask for a raise.  Seriously if your boss is using your query history to determine how much work you are doing he is:

1. A real ball buster
2. Clueless

Answer (score 1):

Get Mladen Prajdic's [SSMS Tools Pack](http://ssmstoolspack.com/). It can keep a running history (in a database, on the local file system, or on a network share IIRC) of queries you are working on and/or executing, and you can customize how often it auto-saves for you. It won't tell you how much time you spent staring at the screen between edits or reviewing query results, but it should be a start.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

There is nothing built in and immediatley avaliable within SQL Server that does this. There are any number of ways such functionality can be implemented, but none are simple or trivial, and a skilled DBA could run rings around 'em anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for looking up on what I have done during the day. This will be applicable to you ONLY if the the window title of whatever software, changes depending on what you are currently working on.

```
Eg: My Awesome SQL Software - Query1.sql
    My Awesome SQL Software - newQuery.sql
    My Awesome SQL Software - Results of Table 1
```

Manic Time will track individual applications + their window title.

http://www.manictime.com/